# ViewController Scene gets cleared when transitioning between scenes

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, segue, skshapenode

Is the UIScene discarded when switching views? Whenever I try to switch views, the nodes that the User added (SkShapenodes by drawing) and then come back to the UIScene with the drawing, the SkShapenodes are gone. Any help? Is this normal? How can i prevent this?

Comment: How are you switching views and coming back?  Are you really going back to the original scene with the drawing or are your creating a new drawing scene and going to that one?

Comment: Well I'm using a segue button. If you want I can post a video and put the link here?

Comment: I'm not sure maybe it's a problem with the zPosition?

Comment: @dan sorry for the late reply but i am using a segue. im not sure maybe the problem is im creating a new view?